# How to import all data from a sqlite db into a Django non-rel db

Tags: python, django-models, csv, django-nonrel

I have a sqlite db with some records that I want to import into my Django non-rel db models.

Is the best way just to export the sqlite as a csv and then import the csv?

Something like suggested here: [how to import csv data into django models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459979/how-to-import-csv-data-into-django-models)   or here:  http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/633/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a simple (regular) django project and use [`inspectdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb) to create the initial models from your sqlite db, then use [`dumpdata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-dumpdata) to save it to files.  You can later use [`loaddata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata) in your new project to load it into your models.

If you need further processing, you can create a small script that copies data from the old models to the new models.