# Import csv into django models

Tags: django

I have models defined as

```
class Event(models.Model):
    event_id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    OS_CHOICE=(('Win 2003','windows 2003'),
        ('Win 2008','Windows 2008'),
        ('Win XP','Windows XP'),
        ('Win VISTA','Win VISTA'),
        ('Win 2007','Windows 2007'),
        )
    windows=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=OS_CHOICE,default='Win 2003')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return " %s, event_id :%s" \
            % (self.windows, self.event_id)
    class Meta:
        db_table= 'event'
        verbose_name_plural='events'

class Eventgroups(models.Model):
    event=models.ManyToManyField(Event)
    group_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s,  %s" \
            % (self.group_name, self.event)
    class Meta:
        db_table= 'eventgroup'
        verbose_name_plural='eventgroups'

class Groups_import(models.Model):
    event_id=models.IntegerField()
    windows=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    group_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I want to write a view that imports a csv to database with the above model definition.The user will be asked to browse to where the csv file is located and click on a button to import csv.
Anybody with an insight on how to do this please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- [django-adaptors](http://django-adaptors.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
- [django-csv-importer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-csv-importer/)

See [how to import csv data into django models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459979/how-to-import-csv-data-into-django-models)

Or you can write your own routines:

```
# sudo code
file = request.FILES['fileUpload']
data = [row for row in csv.reader(file.read().splitlines())]
for raw in data:
    _, created = Event.objects.get_or_create(
            event_id=row[0],
            windows=row[1]
            )
```

Comment: Thanks Fragres.Did you consider the M2M field in Eventgroups? and did you mean for row in data:

Comment: If you want to use one of these libs, use django-adaptors which is kind of the newest version of django-csv-importer