# csv file import to django

Tags: django, csv, sqlite

I am trying to import a csv comma delimited file to django model. I have seen many methods like csvimporter, django-csvimport, django-adaptor . Please suggest which import tool will works fine. It would help me more if the steps are briefly listed to import the csv file.