# how to import data to database using django

Tags: django, database

I am trying to import data from excel sheet to database using Django but its not working.

excel file is consist of 2 columns headers.

```
id -
name
```

> Errors Line number: 1 - 'id' None, test Traceback (most recent call
>   last): File
>   "C:\Users\LTGM~1\Desktop\TESTFO~1\testanal\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py",
>   line 492, in import_row instance, new =
>   self.get_or_init_instance(instance_loader, row) File
>   "C:\Users\LTGM~1\Desktop\TESTFO~1\testanal\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py",
>   line 269, in get_or_init_instance instance =
>   self.get_instance(instance_loader, row) File
>   "C:\Users\LTGM~1\Desktop\TESTFO~1\testanal\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py",
>   line 263, in get_instance return instance_loader.get_instance(row)
>   File
>   "C:\Users\LTGM~1\Desktop\TESTFO~1\testanal\lib\site-packages\import_export\instance_loaders.py",
>   line 31, in get_instance field = self.resource.fields[key] KeyError:
>   'id'

I tried the `import_export` module.

1. create the class in models.py
2. create the resource in resources.py
3. create the admin in the admin.py
4. create the function in the views.py

## models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class criminal_type(models.Model):
    criminal_typeID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

## resources.py

```
from import_export import resources
from .models import criminal_type
# from .models import Mouhafazat


class criminal_type_resource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = criminal_type
```

## admin.py

```
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import criminal_type

@admin.register(criminal_type)
class CriminalTypeAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from tablib import Dataset


# Create your views here.

def simple_uploadCriminalType(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        criminalType = criminal_type_resource()
        dataset = Dataset()
        newCriminalType = request.FILES['myfile']

        imported_data = dataset.load(newCriminalType.read(),format="xlsx")
        result = criminalType.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True)  # Test the data import

        if not result.has_errors():
            criminalType.import_data(dataset, dry_run=False)  # Actually import now

    return render(request, 'core/simple_upload.html')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import data from excel spreadsheet to django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019267/import-data-from-excel-spreadsheet-to-django-model)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. " its not working" is the most useless description of a problem. Instead, describe exactly what happens, and, in the case of an exception, post the _exact_ exception message __and__ the full traceback. Note that most of the time, carefully reading the exception message and traceback are enough to understand what went wrong, where, and why.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers i had asked before a question with all the  needed details ( the error and the traceback)but i did not get any answer so i delete it.

Comment: Giving less details is certainly not going to help, quite on the contrary...

Comment: so i will edit my question and add the details.hope that someone will have the answer or at least the guide.