# Import csv to django model using csvImporter

Tags: python, django, csv-import

I am trying to import data from a csv file to a django model. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459979/how-to-import-csv-data-into-django-models) thread, which lead me to the documentation for [CSVImporter](http://django-csv-importer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Since I have already declared a model in my django app, the documentation suggests I use the following code:

```
>>> from my_projects.models import Person
>>> from csvImporter.model import CsvDbModel
>>>
>>> class MyCsvModel(CsvDbModel):
>>>
>>>     class Meta:
>>>        dbModel = Person
>>>        delimiter = ";"
```

So I did this:

```
from polls.models import Question
from csvImporter.model import CsvDbModel
  File "/Users/ytk/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/csvImporter/model.py", line 134
    except ValueError,e :
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax is incompatible with python 3. The correct syntax in Python3 is

```
except ValueError as e:
    ...
```

This library doesn't support python 3, but exists pull request to make support https://github.com/anthony-tresontani/csv_importer/pulls