# CSV not importing to django models

Tags: python, django, csv, django-models

I'm trying to create a django web app that uses data from CSV's. I've created a django model to house the data from these csv's, I've stored all the csv's in STATIC_ROOT. When I load the page, the called template (datalandingpage.html) loads with no problem. However, when I check django admin, none of the CSVs have been imported. If I were to guess, I think the shortcoming has something to do with django not being able to find the files (though I'm just guessing, I could very well be wrong since I'm a relatively new developer). Below is all the relevant code I've written as an attempt.

Edit: So it looks like my view function may be skipping straight to the render part, which may be why I don't see any errors when it runs. Any ideas as to why this may be the case?

settings.py:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/data')
```

models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

class Data(models.Model):
     # A bunch of model objects (CharField/IntegerFields mainly)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Data Sets'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.someobject
```

views.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from .models import Data
import csv
import os

def landing(request):

# Opens all csv files in specified directory
directory = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT)
for files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".csv"):
            f = open(file, 'r')
            reader = csv.reader(f)

            #Checks the rows/columns and tries to find the specified string that marks the start of data
            for i, row in enumerate(reader):
                target_string = "Some string in the CSV"
                if target_string in row:
                    target_row = i
                    return target_row
                    break

            #Checks the rows/columns and tries to find the specified string that marks the end of data
            for j, row in enumerate(reader):
                end_target_string = "Another string in the CSV"
                if end_target_string in row:
                    end_target_row = j
                    return end_target_row
                    break

            #Begins parsing the csv, but skips until two rows past the target beginning string
            for k, row in enumerate(reader):

                #imports csv data when the row number is between target string and target end string
                if k >= (target_row + 2):
                    row = row.split(',')
                    DataSource = Data.objects.create()
                    DataSource.someobject1 = row[0]
                    DataSource.someobject2 = row[1]
                    DataSource.save()

                # When the parse gets to the row with the end string, it closes the file.
                elif k >= end_target_row:
                    reader.close()
                    break

        # Prints something if the file isn't a csv file
        else:
            print "This isn't a csv file"

return render(request, "Data/datalandingpage.html")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to import csv data into django models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459979/how-to-import-csv-data-into-django-models)

Comment: Do you see any errors when the view is executing? What is the status code that is returned? I see some errors there that should, as far as I can tell, be causing some issues.

Comment: @sytech I don't see any errors when the view is executing, just status code 200's. So I did some working and it may be that the function just skips to the render part. Any idea why this may be the case?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up re-writing the script and it worked. I think my strange looping structure caused the script to not work as intended (or at all, really). I also used bulk_create instead of having to call save after every row to make the process more efficient. Here's the version that works:

views.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from .models import Data
import os
import csv, sys


def import_data(request):

    # Opens all csv files in specified directory

    directory = os.path.join('Some Target Directory')
    count = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith(".csv"):
                file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
                with open(file_path) as f:
                     reader = csv.reader(f)

                    #Checks the rows/columns and tries to find the specified string that marks the start of data

                    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
                        target_string = "Some Target String"
                        if target_string in row:

                        #Skips to the next line (where the data starts) when the target string is found

                            true_target_row = next(reader)
                            for row in reader:

                                #Counter tells you which file number is importing. 

                                print "importing file number %d" %(count)

                                #Creates a bunch of objects

                                objects = [
                                    Data(
                                        SomeObject = row [n],
                                        ...
                                        ...
                                )
                                for row in reader if row[0] != "Some Target End String"
                            ]

                            # Does a bulk_create after the file is completed

                            Data.objects.bulk_create(objects)
                            count += 1

            # Prints something if the file isn't a csv file

            else:
                print "This isn't a csv file"

    print "Imported %d files! All done!" %(count)

    return render(request, "Data/DataLandingPage.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to create a list of model from a CSV file. You might consider using an existing library for this: http://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with how you're looping over the directories and opening the files. `os.walk` yields for each directory walked a tuple of `(root_dir, directories, files)` where `directories` is a tuple of directory names that are found in `root_dir` and `files` is a tuple of file names found in `root_dir`

In your code you have the following:

```
for files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".csv"):
            f = open(file, 'r')
            reader = csv.reader(f)
```

This would not do what you probably think it does and will undoubtedly result in an `AttributeError` because `files` in `for files in os.walk(...)` will always have two tuples in it and tuples do not have a `.endswith` method.

Furthermore, when you correctly loop over files provided by `os.walk` -- they are just file names. You have to join the path with the root directory.

To fix, you should modify this as follows....

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(".csv"):
            file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
            with open(file_path) as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f)
```

Notice that this unpacks the tuples yielded by `os.walk` into `root, dirs, files` now `files` is actually a list of file names. Additionally, `os.path.join(root, filename)` is used to create the full path to the file from the name.

Also note I modified this to use the [`with open(...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282967/how-to-open-a-file-using-the-open-with-statement) context manager. Code under this block executes with the file opened and once the block ends the file will be closed for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I made changes as you suggested. However, because I was seeing no errors when loading the view (again, the template loads perfectly fine), it led me to think that the function I have just skips to the render part. Any idea why this may be the case?