# from adaptor.model import CsvModel

Tags: python, django, csv

I am trying to use the CsvModel module from django-adaptors. However, when i use from adaptor.model import CsvModel and makemigrations, below errors occured.

Can anyone advise the reason why? my code in the model is as follows:

```
from django.db import models
from adaptor.model import CsvModel
from adaptor.fields import CharField, DecimalField


class User(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null=True, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name


 class Profile(models.Model):
    rubbish = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 1000, decimal_places=3, null=True)
    user = models.CharField(max_length = 50, unique = True, null=True)
    hobby = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null=True)
    job = models.CharField(max_length = 60, null=True)

class Trial(CsvModel):
    rubbish = DecimalField()
    user = CharField()
    hobby = CharField()

    class Meta:
        dbmodel = Profile
        delimiter = ','
        has_header = True
```

Error message is as follows:

```
File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/pangkachun/Desktop/smallpro2/small_pro/small/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from adaptor.model import CsvModel
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adaptor/model.py", line 269
    except ValueError, e:
                     ^ . `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using python3.6 but the library looks like it is made for python2.5-
For Python 3 it should be

```
except ValueError as e:
```

[source](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/pyporting.html#capturing-the-currently-raised-exception)

You may have to find a different csv plugin like [django-csvimport](https://github.com/edcrewe/django-csvimport) and possibly change your strategy accordingly

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with django-adaptors?