# Django objects.get_or_create(): passing arguments from dictionary or list

Tags: python, django

I currently have a django management command to import CSV files, which is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15961736/2052575).  The main business is done by the following line in a loop:

```
created = Customer.objects.get_or_create(account_no = int(row[0]), name = row[1])
```

However, because I have a number of different models to run this on, I wish to put the above code inside a function, and pass the attributes and row keys in from a dictionary; so I'd defnine something like:

```
csv_columns = { 0: 'account_no', 1: 'name' }
```

However I don't know how to run the `get_or_create` function based on this.  I'm sure this should be simple.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your dictionaries should look like this:

```
csv_row = {"account_no": "123-456", "name": "v25"}
```

Make sure you use a [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) so that you're reading the csv file's header and then iterating the rows of the csv file correctly, i.e. the keys of each dict yielded are the column names.

Then, the `get_or_create` call will be a simple unpacking, something like this:

```
Customer.objects.get_or_create(**csv_row)
```

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't get this method to work, but with help from your link to DictReader, was able to implement this whereby I can specify the django field names IN the CSV which is sufficient for my needs.