# How can I populate a django database using a script file?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I built a small django app and created some models. Now I would like to populate the database (the tables and rows do already exist) using a python script since I have to read the information I want to populate the database with, from multiple external files. Is there any way to do that?

EDIT:
Python 3.7
Django 3.0

Comment: There are two major ways: using fixtures or data migrations.

Comment: I am new into Django, but I guess the the script file must use the python shell like:

% python manage.py shell
>>> from products.models  import Product
>>> Product.objects.all()
>>> Product.objects.create(title='new product 2', description='another one', price='19312', summary='sweet')

Comment: so you mean like piping the command into the django shell?

Comment: @funnydman how would you do it using migrations? (Just answer so I can have a look)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use any python routine to read files, process the content, create your model instances and save them the to the database by using a custom [Django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/).

check this out: [how to import csv data into django models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459979/how-to-import-csv-data-into-django-models)