# How can I automate the creation of django model instances from a script?

Tags: python, django, django-models, automation, django-views

I'm fairly new to Django and recently created a website to group and display COVID-19 data in my home country.

I am recording daily new cases, deaths, and recoveries by city using a CaseDeclaration model:

```
class CaseDeclaration(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(default=lambda: CaseDeclaration.latest_date())
    new_cases = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    new_deaths = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    new_recoveries = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    source = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

It is working properly but I am now writing a script that will automate the process of creating CaseDeclaration objects off of publications made by a local news outlet on Facebook. The script is in a **text_extractor.py** file next to models.py and views.py. At this point it takes a txt file and extracts the data into a dictionary like so (keys are the city names):

```
>>> print(extract_data())
{'non répertorié': {'new_deaths': 6, 'new_recoveries': 344}, 'Antananarivo': {'new_cases': 388}, 'Ambatondrazaka': {'new_cases': 13}, 'Toliara': {'new_cases': 9}, 'Fianarantsoa': {'new_cases': 7}, 'Mahajanga': {'new_cases': 6}, 'Ambositra': {'new_cases': 3}, 'Miarinarivo': {'new_cases': 2}, 'Toamasina': {'new_cases': 2}, 'Sambava': {'new_cases': 1}}
```

And the date *extract_date()* returns the format 8-11-2020 as a str.

I now need a way to **take that data and create model instances** for each city, all without me having to use the python shell or admin panel. And finally **program the script to execute daily**.

What I have tried so far:

1. import models into my text_extractor.py file and use Model().save() from there, but my file could not import models, and I could not figure out how to run the script from the server from there.
2. create a Model Manager for CaseDeclaration and give it a create_from_dict() function
3. create a function that will create the model instances and run it every time the home page is loaded **and* the latest CaseDeclaration object is not from today. Also, here my custom .py file isn't recognized as a module and can't be imported.

Whichever way would eventually work I am not capable to figure it out by myself and online resources have been really limited, so I am hoping you can help out. Thank you so much in advance!

EDIT: Current code
**text_extractor.py**

```
def extract_data():
    return find_data(region_to_cities(join_words(cleanup_covid19(extracted_data))))

def extract_date():
    temp = find_date(region_to_cities(join_words(cleanup_covid19(extracted_data))))
    date = '-'.join(str(e) for e in temp)
    return date
```

**views.py**

```
def extractCaseDeclaration():
    from .text_extractor import extract_data, extract_date
    data = extract_data()
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(extract_date(), '%m-%d-%Y')

    for key, values in data.items():
        city = ''
        if "-" in key:
            city = string.capwords(key, '-')
        else:
            city = string.capwords(key)
        print(city)
        city = City.objects.get(name = city)

extractCaseDeclaration()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459979/how-to-import-csv-data-into-django-models

Answer (score 1):

You can run the python script in the manage.py shell
just start the shell:

```
python manage.py shell
```

and run the code snippet below

```
>>>exec(open('/python_automate_script.py').read())
```

This will run the python script.

There are other ways, you can find more details in this [website](https://fedingo.com/how-to-run-python-script-in-django-project/)