# populate django database, txt or CSV file

Tags: python, django, web, django-models, django-rest-framework

How to populate django database, with txt(delimited by "|") or CSV file? From admin panel on site?

the customer asked to make it so that he could replenish the site database, txt document or CSV table

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to import csv data into django models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459979/how-to-import-csv-data-into-django-models)

Comment: what about txt?

Comment: You can read txt files but it's plain text and working with that it's very difficult. The best practice may be using csv files