# Read data from google sheets and dump into Postgres database using python and django

Tags: python-3.x, django, google-sheets, django-models, google-api

I have data on google sheets and I want to dump data into the Postgres database using python and Django.
Note that each row in a google sheet contains information for different tables like it could be a foreign key etc.
Am looking for any tutorial/blog to serve this purpose.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Have not done anything yet, looking for tutorial to start

Answer (score 0):

Try any of the resources below

1. https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/
2. django-import-export: A widget that allows you to import excel files from admin section. It's very easy to install, here you find the installation tutorial, and here an example. https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
3. You can also try [this](http://mitchfournier.com/2011/10/11/how-to-import-a-csv-or-tsv-file-into-a-django-model/) showing you how to import data into django
4. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459979/how-to-import-csv-data-into-django-models) also works.

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I have data on the google sheets not in the hard drive as a CSV downloaded file